# Плавное появление объекта на CSS

Tags: css3

Учусь верстать сайт из PSD макетов, столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне нужно что-бы при наведении справа от объекта появлялся еще один с плавной анимацией при появлении, исчезании. Подскажите, что собственно с моим кодом не так (Объект не появляется вовсе)

```
 #square {
 width: 41px;
 height: 41px;
 background: #b9b9ba;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position: relative;
 left: 37%;
 top: -165px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 }


#second_block {
display:none;
margin-left:-350px;
padding:10px;
margin-top:17px;
background:#000;
height:200px;
-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#square:hover #second_block {
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:120px;
z-index:9999;
width:400px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="square"><div class='second_block'>
</div></div>
```

[image: Код]

Comment: кода то и не видно, точнее разметки.

Comment: Он виден на скриншоте, сейчас прикреплю его отдельно

Comment: это не разметка.

Comment: Как я сказал выше, я учусь. Убедительно прошу свой хейт оставить при себе))

Comment: Имелось  в виду, что HTML тоже надо бы прикрепить.

Comment: Исходя из макета, мне нужно что-бы это дело выглядело так: http://imgur.com/a/zEewE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
.info{   
   width: 41px;
   height: 41px;
   background: #b9b9ba;
   border-radius: 10px;
   position: relative;   
   opacity: 0.5;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
 }
 .info:hover .info-tooltip{
   opacity: 1;     
 }
 
.info-tooltip{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 100%; 
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #F2782A;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  transform: translateY(-50%);    
  transition: .5s;
}
.info-tooltip:before,
.info-tooltip:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.info-tooltip:before{  
  margin-top: -8px;  
  border-width: 8px 20px 8px 0;
  border-color: transparent #2E2E2E transparent transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}
.info-tooltip:after{  
  margin-top: -10px;  
  border-width: 10px 24px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #F2782A transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class='info-tooltip'>Text tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip tooltip</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

в HTML коде у вас используется **class** second_block
а в CSS он уже как **id** second_block

классы в CSS указываются с точкой, например **.block**
id в CSS указываются с решеткой, например **#block**

По поводу анимации, гуглите примеры по запросу "transition css3"

ps
Насколько мне известно, анимация CSS невозможна если у элемента изначально display:none; а при наведении становится display:block;

В таких случаях используется js.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой метод - ставить не display: none, а opacity: 0, visibility: hidden. а на ховер вешать opacity: 1, visibility: visible. Тогда плавность будет.